# video streaming between two iphones?

Tags: iphone, ipad, iphone-sdk-3.0, gksession

is it possible to show what is showing in camera in one IPhone to another iphone through
bluetooth(GKSession)..Remote Live is available in Appstore.any idea pls?

Answer (score 1):

I have never developed for iPhone before, but the idea sounds like it should be possible. I would take the approach of remote desktop basically. On the host phone, start up the camera and capture the image/video stream, then on the receiving phone have the client app that pairs to the host via bluetooth (wouldnt a wireless connection be better?) and send the data to the client phone to be rendered?